# data persistence with firebase storage like firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Does firebase storage have a built-in capability to automatically persist data offline like firestore, I can't find such feature in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not.  You would have to implement that yourself, or find a some sort of library that does what you want.

Comment: @Amin the question is about Cloud Storage, not Firestore. They are completely different products.